# Leer el archivo separado por comas JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Estoy leyendo un archivo de texto, funciona bien para leer el archivo me imprime el archivo correctamente pero quier ahora leer cada linea y separarla por espacios imprimir solo la primer palabra y despues de con condicionales decidir si imprimir el siguiente o no. Anexo el codigo que tengo

```
if (args.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Se debe escribir el nombre del archivo a leer, intentalo de nuevo");
                // terminamos el programa. 
                System.exit(1); // enviamos 1 que significa error
                }
                String fileName2 = args[0]; // guardamos el nombre del archivo a traducir.
                try {                    
                    FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(fileName2);
                    // instanciar a Scanner enviando el FileInputStream
                    Scanner scann = new Scanner(file2);
                                   
                    String linea;                        
                                                                               
                            while (scann.hasNextLine()) {                   
                                linea = scann.next();
                                System.out.printf(linea);                                                                                                                                           
                            }
                            System.out.println("Finalizado con exito");                                
                                                    
                        file2.close();                   
                        scann.close(); 
                } catch (Exception error) {                    
                System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo " + fileName2 ); // posible error al leer el archivo de texto
                System.exit(1);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

A ver, se me ocurre que podrías usar substring para obtener la primera palabra y a partir de ahí, usarla para los condiciones que necesitas.

- indexOf buscas donde esta el primer espacio en blanco y devuelve su índice.
- substring obtienes el string que va de 0 a el carácter en blanco (la primera palabra).
- Una vez tengas la palabra ya puedes construir el condicional y mostrar la frase o
  saltarte una linea utilizando el `scann.next()` de nuevo.

```
while (scann.hasNextLine()) {                   
    linea = scann.next();

    int primerEspacio = linea.indexOf(" ");
    String primeraPalabra= linea.substring(0, primerEspacio);

    if (primeraPalabra.equals("loquesea")) {
        //Saltarse una linea
        scann.next();
    }
    else {
      // mostrar la linea
      System.out.printf(linea);
    }
 }
```

Otra forma podría ser utilizando la función `linea.split(" ")`, con la que obtendrías un array con cada palabra.

Split recibe como argumento una expresión regular. Según esta expresión hará la separación.[split documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
Ejemplo, separando por espacios:

```
String text = "Hola buenas, como estas?";
String[] splitText = text.split(" ");

for (int i=0; i<splitText.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(splitText[i]);
}
```

Cada elemento de **"splitText"** será:

- elemento 0: Hola
- elemento 1: buenas,
- elemento 2: como
- elemento 3: estas?

El problema aquí es evitar los caracteres especiales, que tendrás que buscar una expresión regular que se adapte a lo que necesites.

El problema que hay aquí son los caracteres especiales. Por si te sirve, esta expresión separa por espacios ignorando los caracteres especiales:
`splitText.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");`
Esta web esta bien para ver como hacer las expresiones: [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Hola, Gracias por el tip, me podrias decir como funciona el linea.split(" ") soy nueva programando en Java y aun no termino de comprenderlo

Comment: Hola Jen, por supuesto, lo añadí en otra respuesta, espero que te sirva!

Comment: @Benito-B gracias por avisar! ya la eliminé y añadí a la respuesta anterior

Comment: Ahora si, excelente respuesta @fytta! :)

Comment: @fytta una disculpa tendrás un método por el cual contactarte por aparte, por favor